# How to count the lines per url using concurrent futures?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have multiple urls like the following.

- https://website.com/files/123.txt
- https://website.com/files/456.txt
- https://website.com/files/789.txt

Each url has data like the following.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I want to count the number of lines each url has using concurrent futures.

Here is what I have.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['https://website.com/files/123.txt',
        'https://website.com/files/456.txt',
        'https://website.com/files/789.txt']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the number of lines in each URL's data, you can create a function `count_lines` to return the number of lines instead of the data itself:

```
def count_lines(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        data = conn.read()
        num_lines = len(data.splitlines())
        return num_lines
```

And them modify the rest of your code like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(count_lines, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            num_lines = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r has %d lines' % (url, num_lines))
```

Comment: Thanks, helps it make sense. I'm going to write the count function a little different. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to the Stack Overflow community!